# Displaying details from list of persons using php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display a list of persons. On clicking the list , more details on the person must be shown.

members.php:  -a page to list all members

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our members are</h1>
    <?php 
    include 'config.php';
    session_start();
    $sql = "SELECT name from users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo '<table>';
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   
                        {
                             echo '<tr>';
                             $_SESSION['selection'] = $row['name'];
                             echo '<td><a href = "view.php">'.$row['name'].'</a></td>'; 
                             echo '</tr>';
                        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
    $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
```

view.php  -the page to show more details:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'config.php';
    session_start();
    $pkey = $_SESSION['selection'];
    $new = "SELECT * FROM users where name = '$pkey'";
    $display = $conn->query($new);
    $result = $display->fetch_assoc();
    echo 'Name:'.$result['name'];
    echo 'Rollno:'.$result['rool_no'];
    echo 'Description:'.$result['description'];

    $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
```

on using session , always the details of last person in the list is shown. 
How to display the corresonding details??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally you are saving last name in the session variable  $_SESSION['selection'] = $row['name'];  so you getting the last name .while loop end with last name and you saving it in session.you are not using session as array know that.

my advice is not use session.  session is not required here.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   
{
     echo '<tr>';
     $_SESSION['selection'] = $row['name'];
     echo '<td><a href = "view.php">'.$row['name'].'</a></td>'; 
     echo '</tr>';
}
```

change these lines in members.php

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   
{
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td><a href = "view.php?name=$row['name']">'.$row['name'].'</a></td>'; 
     echo '</tr>';
}
```

and change these line in view.php

```
<body>
<?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();
$pkey = $_REQUEST['name'];//change this line alone
$new = "SELECT * FROM users where name = '$pkey'";
$display = $conn->query($new);
$result = $display->fetch_assoc();
echo 'Name:'.$result['name'];
echo 'Rollno:'.$result['rool_no'];
echo 'Description:'.$result['description'];

$conn->close();
?>
```